# Iterating and appending dictionary values in another dictionary

Tags: python

```
disks={'1':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5}
mem={'1':11,'2':12,'3':13,'4':14,'5':15}
cpu={'1':21,'2':22,'3':23,'4':24,'5':25}
Stats={}
Values={}
for i in range(1,len(disks)+1):
    Index="value"+str(i)
    total = disks['%s'%i]
    memory =  mem['%s'%i]
    cpus= cpu['%s'%i]
    Values["cpu"]=cpus
    Values["total"]=total
    Values["memory"]=memory

       
    print(Index) # shows right value
    print(Values) # shows right value
    Stats[Index]=Values
    print(Stats)
       
       
print (Stats)
```

Individual values are printed fine, however the final disctioanary print keys properly as value1, value2 -- however the values are all for the last value as we can see here:

```
value1
{'cpu': 21, 'total': 1, 'memory': 11}
{'value1': {'cpu': 21, 'total': 1, 'memory': 11}}
value2
{'cpu': 22, 'total': 2, 'memory': 12}
{'value1': {'cpu': 22, 'total': 2, 'memory': 12}, 'value2': {'cpu': 22, 'total': 2, 'memory': 12}}
value3
{'cpu': 23, 'total': 3, 'memory': 13}
{'value1': {'cpu': 23, 'total': 3, 'memory': 13}, 'value2': {'cpu': 23, 'total': 3, 'memory': 13}, 'value3': {'cpu': 23, 'total': 3, 'memory': 13}}
value4
{'cpu': 24, 'total': 4, 'memory': 14}
{'value1': {'cpu': 24, 'total': 4, 'memory': 14}, 'value2': {'cpu': 24, 'total': 4, 'memory': 14}, 'value3': {'cpu': 24, 'total': 4, 'memory': 14}, 'value4': {'cpu': 24, 'total': 4, 'memory': 14}}
value5
{'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}
{'value1': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}, 'value2': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}, 'value3': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}, 'value4': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}, 'value5': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}}

FINAL value: 
{'value1': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}, 'value2': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}, 'value3': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}, 'value4': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}, 'value5': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}}
```

Something I am missing which somehow I am not able to think/figure out. Quick tips welcome

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Stepping through your code with a debugger to see how each line changes your variables is usually super-helpful and an absolutely essential skill for a programmer.

Comment: You can do it with dict comprehension: `Stats = {f'value{i}': {'cpu': c, 'total': t, 'memory': m} for i, (c, t, m) in enumerate(zip(cpu.values(), disks.values(), mem.values()), 1)}`. It will work starting from python 3.6.

Comment: that's great advice, will surely look more into this Pranav! 
That looks complicated for my level, but let me get deeper into it. thanks, Olvin!

Answer (score 1):

Your program is almost correct, just move `Values={}` inside for-loop (to make a new dictionary and not use old one):

```
disks={'1':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5}
mem={'1':11,'2':12,'3':13,'4':14,'5':15}
cpu={'1':21,'2':22,'3':23,'4':24,'5':25}
Stats={}
for i in range(1,len(disks)+1):
    Values={}                    # <-- move Values here
    Index="value"+str(i)
    total = disks['%s'%i]
    memory =  mem['%s'%i]
    cpus= cpu['%s'%i]
    Values["cpu"]=cpus
    Values["total"]=total
    Values["memory"]=memory

       
    # print(Index) # shows right value
    # print(Values) # shows right value
    Stats[Index]=Values
    # print(Stats)
       
       
print (Stats)
```

Prints:

```
{'value1': {'cpu': 21, 'total': 1, 'memory': 11}, 'value2': {'cpu': 22, 'total': 2, 'memory': 12}, 'value3': {'cpu': 23, 'total': 3, 'memory': 13}, 'value4': {'cpu': 24, 'total': 4, 'memory': 14}, 'value5': {'cpu': 25, 'total': 5, 'memory': 15}}
```

Comment: That's so basic..thanks for your inputs, in coding the complexities totally missed the most basic thing here.. Thanks Andrej! This is an accepted answer, I do not have enough reputation points to upvote though :-)

Comment: @pythondev Everyone started from somewhere :) Nothing wrong with that.